# Is there any way to wait to invoke callback until multiple backbone collection have synced?

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I'd like to run view.render() if both collectionA and collectionB have fired 'sync' event.
Something like this.

```
collectionA = new CollectionA();
collectionB = new CollectionB();

view.listenTo([collectionA, collectionB], 'sync', view.render);

collectionA.fetch(); // do not call view.render yet.
collectionB.fetch(): // call view.render after fetch.
```

I know there is a way to use $.when() or _.after() like this answers.
[How to synchronize multiple Backbone.js fetches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168587/how-to-synchronize-multiple-backbone-js-fetches)

But I think these are not event-driven way.
Is there any event-driven way on Backbone.js?

Answer (score 10):

You can use a combination of underscore's [`after`](http://underscorejs.org/#after) method to only execute the callback when it's been called a number of times, and [`Backbone.Events.once`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-once) to ensure that you don't trigger the handler prematurely, if one of the collections fires two `sync` events, instead of one from each:

```
var callback = _.after(2, view.render);
collectionA.once('sync', callback, view);
collectionB.once('sync', callback, view);
```

Or you can wrap the logic into a utility function, so you can use it with a variable number of event sources:

```
function onceAll(eventSources, eventName, handler, context) {
  handler = _.after(eventSources.length, handler);
  context = context || this;
  _.each(eventSources, function(source) {
      source.once(eventName, handler, context);
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
onceAll([collectionA, collectionB], 'sync', view.render, view);
```

/Code samples not tested.