# Issue with jquery promises and backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to synchronize multiple backbone fetches using jquery promises as mentioned in this SO thread:
[How to synchronize multiple Backbone.js fetches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168587/how-to-synchronize-multiple-backbone-js-fetches)

Here's the code I have currently:

```
$.when(
    this.collection1.fetch(),
    this.collection2.fetch(),
    this.collection3.fetch()).
    done(function(){
      _this.$el.trigger('custom_event');
    }
);
```

My expectation is that done() will get called once all three fetches have received a response, however the done callback is being called immediately while all of the ajax requests are still pending.

I'm using jquery 1.7.1 with backbone 0.9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something must have been off with my environment because the same code is now working as expected.